# Compound Interest Rate Calculation (only interest rate paid) in R

Tags: r

I have a question, how to calculate in R interest rate that is paid over the years:

```
H <- 2000000 # mortgage
i.m <- 0.03/12 # rate per month
year <- 15 # years

a <- (H*i.m*(1+i.m)^(12*year))/
  ((1+i.m)^(12*year)-1)
a # monthly

b <- a*year*12
b # will pay at the end

remain <- (a/i.m)*(1 - (1/((1+i.m)^((year:0)*12)))) # remain to be paid
remain

interest <- H*((1+i.m)^(0:year)-1) # interest rate over the years????
interest
```

http://mortgagevista.com/#m=1&a=2000000&b=3&c=60y&A&B&C&D&oa&ob&oc&od
I am reproducing this plot "Total Interest Paid" (name of the plotline, I am trying to get).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the monthly interest rate paid:

```
interest <- a*(1-(1/(1+i.m)^(0:(year*12))))
```